# Python module's __path__ points to non-existent directory

Tags: python-3.x, package

I have an autogenerated package providing Python 3 bindings for various shared libraries via its submodules. After installing it in one VM (`python3 setup.py install`), it works perfectly. However, in a second VM, the submodule I'm trying to import from the package cannot be found. One difference I can find between the VMs is the package's `__path__` attribute.

On the correctly working VM, the package's `__path__` attribute points to the correct `site-packages` directory (`/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/py_{PACKAGE_NAME}-{DIST_INFO}.egg`), which is indeed where the package and its submodules are located.

On the non-working VM, `__path__` points to `/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/{PACKAGE_NAME}`, which doesn't exist in the filesystem.

So what could cause `__path__` to point to a non-existent path?